# Convert ü to \u00fc

Tags: php

The value saved in the database is *M\u00fcnchen*. I cannot change database, it is a search API. I have to convert user's input *München* to the string saved in the database to match their search term. I need a PHP function for all special signs, as M\u00fcnchen is just an example. How do I achieve it?

All examples I have found treat the database character change. I cannot. It is not my database. Or conversion vice versa: *M\u00fcnchen* to *München*. I tried:
json_encode(), json_decode(), url_encode(). Any other function that can convert it?

Comment: how dit that encoding end up in your database? you probably can reuse that

Comment: It can be solved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061511/6263942) with the RegEx from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061339/#comment126041941_7061511): `html_entity_decode(preg_replace('/\\\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $string));`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a similar function:

```
function beauty_words ($word){
    $word = str_replace("\u00fc","ü",$word); //add many replaces as you wish
    return $word;
}

$word = 'M\u00fcnchen';

$word = beauty_words($word); //'M\u00fcnchen' becomes 'München'
```

Comment: I know that I can replace it one by one. But it's a search API. I cannot know what characters users will use in the search. I am looking for general conversion. Is it possible?